# Simplest way to publish matplotlib-like interactive animation to html?

Tags: python, html, matplotlib, animation, publish

I'm using **matplotlib and python** to make an animated scatter plot with points as 'balls' that bounce around, just like this:

https://jakevdp.github.io/downloads/videos/particle_box.mp4

It is interactive at runtime (with sliders to change velocity, attraction, etc), simulating on the go.
I would like to then publish it with the interactivity and all in html.

Problem: I don't know of a way to publish matplotlib interactivity to html directly.

So can I do it in python? Or is there a better way?
Which library (or program, if different from python) would you recommend as the simplest and fastest for this kind of project? I don't need "pretty" customizations and all that, I just need easy calculations and simulations (python) to then plot in a few easy lines of code (matplotlib). I do need to change the dots (balls) colors though.

I have looked at **mpld3** that should wrap matplotlib around D3js. But I don't know anything about js and it is not very straightforward, so it would take me a bit to learn.

I have also looked at **plotly**, but it doesn't seem to have the same customization of the animation I need.

I have looked at **Dash** with plotly, but it would be a whole new environment to learn, and definitely overkill.

So the questions are: is there a way to output matplotlib interactive animations to html that I haven't found?
If not, what tools would you use to accomplish this project within a fast timeframe and shallow learning curve, based on my beginner/low intermediate python and matplotlib skill level?

Thank you!

Comment: Matplotlib is entirely based on python; using it interactively hence requires a python interpreter running. So if you have a server that runs python, you can publish a matplotlib figure using the `webagg` backend. Alternatively you can publish a notebook that people can view on a notebook server. Else you would need to use a tool other than matplotlib. I think plotly outputs full HTML/JS code that can be embedded. Also Bokeh would work. Those will definitely require to change your code to the respective syntax.

Comment: I would add `Panel` as a library that allows you to make interactive plots with Maplotlib.